# Convert AspectJ project to Java alone project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I am having an old java project with lombok annotationsin eclipse. Out of curiosity, i have modified this project into AspectJ project by adding necessary plugins and (configure -> convert to aspectJ). Now there are error shown everywhere in my project especially in using the getters generated by lombok.

I like to revert it back and convert aspectj to java project. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: no error descriptions, no code samples, ther's really very little to help us help you

Comment: are you using any version control? if yes, just delete eclipse config files and re-import project as maven/gradle project, it will fix your problem.

Comment: I usually also ask for code, usually an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But in this case the problem description is clear enough for me to answer and IMO does not deserve downvotes or close votes. The question is clearly about Eclipse configuration, not about a specific programming problem with Java or AspectJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right-click on project in order to open pop-up context menu
- Open sub-menu "AspectJ Tools"
- Select "Remove AspectJ Capability"

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks man.